# CSS Grid auto populate selected columns

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid, styled-components

I want to auto populate only columns 2 and 3. I Will make a ES6 (javascript) map(). As you can see, the paragraphs /  components remain in the same column. Below are the react codes but basically the problem is css.

[image]

my CSS:

```js
export const WrapperServices = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  color: var(--white);
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0px;

  .first-column {
    grid-column: 1/2;
  }

  .second-and-third-column {
    // i dont no
  }
`
export const Service = styled.p`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`
```

my HTML (JSX) (using react styled components):

```js
<Wrapper>
      <StyledImg image={imageData}" />
      <WrapperServices>
      <span className="first-column">
              <h2>Defesa criminal</h2>
              <p>Conheça nossa atuação</p>
            </span>

            <span className="second-and-third-column">
              <Service>
                <GoLaw size="45" style={{ paddingRight: '10px' }} />
                {data.service1}
              </Service>

              // copy and paste <Service/> component 10 times for testing purpose.
            </span>
  </WrapperServices>
    </Wrapper>
```

Comment: `.second-and-third-column {
  grid-column: 2/3
  }`?

Comment: hi! does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a not so elegant solution:

```css
.first-column {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 6;
  }
```

and remove de span of the grid items

Comment: https://codepen.io/redes_sociais/pen/GRNPggb is a mess

Comment: I don't know how to do